# subprocess.Popen() running a python script is not showing input() prompt

Tags: python, input, subprocess

I'm running a separate python script from my "main" python script using subprocess.Popen(), the reason I use subprocess is that I can capture errors. My problem is that if the separate script uses an input("Enter something: ") statement with a prompt (the text in between the quotes) then it (the prompt) will not be shown in the console when running the "main" script that then, in turn, runs the separate script via subprocess.Popen().

Let's say the "main" python script looks like this:

```py
cmd = "python3 tmp.py"

output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stout, sterror = output.communicate()
```

And "tmp.py" looks like this:

```py
text = input("Enter something: ")
```

When I now run the "main" script the output will just be a blinking cursor where I can enter text, press enter and store the input in the text variable, but the problem is that the prompt ("Enter something: ")
will not be shown/is missing! Why is this? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have redirected `stdout` to a `PIPE`. So that is where the text "Enter something: " goes to...

Comment: I want the output to be: "Enter something: [input]" like if I would run the tmp.py script directly "python3 tmp.py" but subprocess is not showing the prompt part of the input

Comment: Yes. Because the way you started it, the standard output of `python tmp.py` is captured by a pipe back to "main"...